# Como remover um item dinamicamente de um objeto?

Tags: javascript, react, redux

Estou utilizando um state do `reducer`, que contém um objeto neste formato:

```
x = {10: {nome: 'lucas'}, 20:{nome: 'beraldo'}} <br/>
```

E, recebo um id via action.

Gostaria de fazer algo como o `array.filter`, ou o `delete` só que dinamicamente neste objeto, para remover um item, por exemplo:

```
delete x.actionID
```

Só que ele não consegue entender o `action.ID`, já que está vindo da action.

Se fosse um array, faria `x = x.filter(nome != action.id)`, mas como é objeto, não sei como posso tratar.

Comment: Já tentou `delete x[actionID];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode deletar pela chave:

```
delete x[actionID]
```